# PyType_Check() alternative for Python3.5 bindings

Tags: python-3.x, crystal-lang

I am working on a project in Crystal lang which embeds Python3.5 linking Python .so library (no `Python.h` header).
It seems that `PyType_Check()` and other check functions actually are macros, so they're not visible while linking the library.
Is there any other alternative or workarount to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, C macros won't be available in Crystal. However, you'll only need to call them from Crystal. In the compiled C library they're already expanded.

So you can just implement these macros in Crystal. Of course, you'll have to do some unwrapping of nested macros.
To my knowledge there is no simple solution to this. [Bindgen](https://github.com/Papierkorb/bindgen) for example ignores function-like macros as well because they can't be easily converted to Crystal.

Comment: Yes, it seems the only solution is to bind other Python type functions and get a list with all the built in types and implement those macros in Crystal. But is there any possibility to bind the built in variables representing the Python types? They're not pointers, and declaring the same strict in Crystal would be meaningless...

Comment: If they're defined as macros, you can't bind them. They don't exist in the compiled library. In order to use them without the header file, you need to define them in the Crystal bindings. There's nothing bad about that.
You should take a look at bindgen which can generate Crystal bindings automatically from header files.